# How to use 'sed' with piping

Tags: bash, grep, sed

I want to replace a string outputted from `grep`, I have:

```
$ npm info webpack | grep version
```

it outputs me

```
$ version: '2.1.0-beta.12',
```

but I want to have:

```
$ 2.1.0-beta.12
```

So I think I might achieve that using `sed` and replace unnecessary substrings. But here goes the hard part for me:

```
$ npm info webpack | grep version: | sed s/version: /
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command
```

How can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you are going to use  sed, there is no need to also use grep.  Try:

```
npm info webpack | sed -En "s/version: '(.*)',/\1/p"
```

Example:

```
$ echo  "version: '2.1.0-beta.12'," | sed -En "s/version: '(.*)',/\1/p"
2.1.0-beta.12
```

#### Alternative: using awk

Similarly, if we use awk, there is no need to also grep:

```
npm info webpack | awk -F"[ ',]+" '/version:/{print $2}'
```

Example:

```
$ echo  "version: '2.1.0-beta.12'," | awk -F"[ ',]+" '/version:/{print $2}'
2.1.0-beta.12
```

**How it works:**

- `-F"[ ',]+"`

  This tells awk to use spaces, single quotes, or commas or any combination thereof as field separators.
- `/version:/{print $2}`

  If a line contains `version:`, then print the second field.

Comment: The `-E` option obviously means to use ERE syntax, but my GNU sed 4.2.2 manual only mentions `-r`. `-E` works, though!

Comment: @Law29 Yes.  For all reasonably modern GNU sed, however, `-E` is an **undocumented** synonym for `-r`.  The rumor is that POSIX has settled on `-E`, which BSD/OSX already uses, and, if that is added to the final standard, we will all be transitioning to `-E`.

Answer (score 19):

The `sed` substitute command (`s`) expects a search pattern and a replacement string.  You only supplied it with a search pattern. You also should quote strings properly in the shell:

```
$ npm info webpack | grep 'version:' | sed 's/version: //'
```

This will give you the result `'2.1.0-beta.12',`, which is not quite what you want.

Since the output from `grep` is so simple, you may use `cut` with the delimiter `'` to get the second field of the line (without the need for complicated regular expressions):

```
$ npm info webpack | grep -F 'version:' | cut -d "'" -f 2
```

This will give you `2.1.0-beta.12`.

I also added `-F` to `grep` since the string you search for is a *fixed string*, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 7):

First, you may try using `sed`:

```
npm info webpack | grep version: | sed 's/version: //'
```

or you may use `awk`:

```
npm info webpack | grep version: | awk '{print $2}'
```

which is probably easier.